# Share a List Template globally

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, list-template

I know I can create a list template and share it at the site collection level (from the gallery). But is it possible to share a list template across all site collections in a tenant? Similar to what the App Catalog does with add-ins?

Comment: you may want to see if a content type hub would work in your scenario. That will work globally, but it's not a list template, but there are many similarities.

Comment: Yes I guess that would work, but the user would have to create an empty list then attach the content type which is a little more work and understanding on their part

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use a migration tool like Metalogix or Sharegate to deploy the template across the site collection. It's not exactly a solution, more of a workaround, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After you save a list as template, it will be saved in List Template Gallery. 
You can download the template from the List Template Gallery, then upload it to other site collection's List Template Gallery, then you can create the list from other site collections.

Comment: Yep that's true but requires manually deploying it to every site collection